# Как использовать Gradle для добавления Lib'ы?

Tags: android

У меня есть сервер, там папка в папке файлы типа `java` и ресурсы типа `xml`, как используя `gradle` одной строкой добавить их ко мне в проект?

Comment: не думаю ,что это возможно, тем более одной строкой.

Comment: Согласитесь что было бы полезно это, у вас есть куча кастомный либ и вы одной строкой добавляете их в проект...Думаю до вечера оставлю тему, если не будет ничего то закрою

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете залить свою библиотеку на репозитарии, jcenter или maven, и далее подкачивать их в другие проекты грэйдлом с помощью одной строки, как делаем это например с библиотекой appcompat (`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`). Почитайте [тут](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) об этом